# Solving for the upper bound and lower bound of liars, in liar-truth teller problem

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve a truth teller/ Liar problem. A survey of a class is taken. Answers are in the form of a Matrix A, where A[i][j] represents the reply given by the i-th student about the j-th student. If that character is ‘L’ – it means he/she is a liar; if it’s ‘T’ – then it means that, that student is a truth speaker.

Truth-Speaker (‘T’): All his/her replies are true.
Liar (‘L’) : (S)he has made at least one false reply.

ex. 1

```
TLLL  

LTLL                                                                   

LLTL  

LLLT
```

Class contains at least 3 and at most 4 liars, 3 is the lower bound of liars, and 4 is the upper bound.

ex. 2

```
TLTLT 

TTTTT

LLTLL

LLLLL

TLTLT
```

Class contains at least 4 and at most 4 liars

I am not sure how the lower and upper bound was found, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the examples you give you can just follow the logic and see what follows from assuming that a particular person is T. In general you can set up a mixed integer programming problem.

Let x_i=1 if person i is L, and x_i=0 if he is T. Then create a linear function from the statements of every person. For example, from TLTLT create:

```
f_1 = (x_1) + (1-x_2) + (x_3) + (1-x_4) + (x_5)
```

You can see the pattern. For any feasible assignment (that is, a setting of the x variables where there is no contradiction between the x values and the people's statements) you must have that x_1=0 if and only if f_1=0, and x_1=1 if and only if f_1>0, or, since everything is integer, f_1>=1. This is equivalent to f_i>=x_i and f_i<=(N+1)x_i (where N is the number of people). So now you have the system:

```
For all i=1,...,N
    f_i>=x_i
    f_i<=(N+1)x_i
    x_i is 0 or 1
```

and every feasible solution to this system corresponds to a feasible assignment and vice versa.

With these constraints simply minimize and maximize `sum x_i` to get the lower and upper bound on the number of liars.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by minimize and maximize sum x_i, also wouldnt all cases of f_i be 0 since in the linear equation you wrote, whenever it is L (1-xi) occurs. Sorry if this is a bad question, just having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

Comment: Also what language would you use to program this

Comment: If all f_i is 0, then all x_i must be 0 (it's one of the constraints for all i), which would mean that everybody is T, which may not be a feasible solution. The fact that x_i and f_i moves hand in hand, that is, if x_i is 1 then the constraint f_i>=x_i forces f_i to be 1, which means at least one of the terms in f_i is 1, which means there is a divergence from what person i has claimed. And that's good, because that is exactly what x_i=1 is supposed to mean.

Comment: And you can argue the converse, too: if x_i=0, then because of f_i<=(N+1)x_i, f_i must be 0, too, which means there is no divergence, which means person i's claim is true, which is exactly what x_i=0 is supposed to mean.

Comment: As for what programming language to use... There are special libraries to solve MILP problems. Some commercial (though free for academic use), like CPLEX, Gurobi, XPress, some open source like glpk, cbc. There is a solver in Matlab, too. The three commercial ones have all sort of APIs (C, C++, Java, python) and they are supported by various modeling languages, too (like OPL, AMPL, MPL). You would need to set up the model using your your favorite API or modelling language, then invoke the solver.

Comment: BTW, the constraint set I described will most likely have many feasible solutions, and the number of x variables at 1 may be different in them. The sum of x variables is the number of liars, so when you minimize `sum x_i` you are trying to find a solution which has the least possible number of liars (there may be multiple such solutions, but one is enough), that is the minimum possible value for sum x_i is a lower bound on the number of liars. Similarly the maximum possible value for sum x_i is an upper bound.

Comment: The pre-specified TLTLT or whatever sequences that are translated to the f_i expressions will drive the minimum up from 0, and the maximum down from N.

Answer (score 0):

**For the first example:**

- all 4 students only say that they are telling the truth and that the rest are lying
- They could all be lying for all we know - so the upper bound is 4
- For the lower bound we can assume 1 is telling the truth and that makes sense logically. If we tried to say that more than 1 is true
  than this is not possible since the students would say each other are
  lying - thus the lower bound is 3

**For the second example it takes a little more logic to figure out:**

- the 4th student says that he is lying - which means he must be lying and that at least one of his claims about the other 4 students lying must be a lie (the claim that he is lying is obviously true) - this means that at least one of the students is not lying so the upper bound becomes 4 and the lower becomes 1
- student 2 says that they are all true - which we just proved is wrong so he must be lying
- this leaves us with students 1,3 and 5 who all say that student 3 is telling the truth. Since we know that at least one student is telling the truth - then student 3 must be telling the truth (since they all say so).
- Then from what student 3 says we know the rest are lying - so the upper=lower=4 liars